# Collecting features from network.foward() in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, pytorch

So basically I want to achieve the same goal as in this code but in TensorFlow

```
def get_function(network, loader):
    ''' Collect function (features) from the self.network.module.forward_features() routine '''
    features = []
    for batch_idx, (inputs, targets) in enumerate(loader):
        inputs, targets = inputs.to('cpu'), targets.to('cpu')

        features.append([f.cpu().data.numpy().astype(np.float16) for f in network.forward_features(inputs)])

    return [np.concatenate(list(zip(*features))[i]) for i in range(len(features[0]))]
```

Are there any clean ways to do this with TensorFlow iterator? Here is the torch code that I want to replicate in TensorFlow. https://pastecode.io/s/b03cpoyv

Comment: What's an issue you face exactly? Have you attempted to achieve this in tf? It should be doable.

Comment: Yeah I am trying to achieve this in tf but I am struggling

Comment: Please add what you've tried. Also the passing input and expected output. What do you want as a return of these functions? What I'm assuming from your question until now is that the solution in tf would be pretty straightforward and more concise than the above torch code.

Comment: So in this example I pass LeNet(num_classes=10) and torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, sampler=SequentialSampler(dataset), drop_last=True) as an input, and my current tries are not really worth posting :)

Comment: I mean the size. What size you're giving to the model and what is the expected output size? Sorry, I should be more descriptive.

Comment: input = (1000, 2, 1, 28, 28), output = (4, 1000, 10, 12, 12)

Comment: Is it 3d modeling by any chance? input: (batch_size, depth, channel, w, h)?

Comment: I am not sure how it is done in pycharm, i have not been using it at all, i am getting dataset like this: torchvision.datasets.MNIST('./data', download=True, train=False, transform=TRANSFORMS_MNIST), and then passing subset like this: torch.utils.data.Subset(dataset, list(range(0, 1000)))

Comment: [here](https://www.kaggle.com/usingtc/lenet-with-pytorch/script) is the torch script, with LeNet and MNist, please try to relate it with yours.

Comment: Ok I will be more specific, I got .t7 checkpoints from LeNet training and thats my script right now: https://pastecode.io/s/b03cpoyv. I want to get the same output of the checkpoints from tensorflow .h5 checkpoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, I just need to ensure that you understand your original [torch](/questions/tagged/torch) [code](https://pastecode.io/s/b03cpoyv) properly. So, here's your workflow

```
class LeNet(nn.Module):
     def forward:
         # few bunch of layers 
         return output

     def forward_features:
         # same as forward function 
         return [each layer output]
```

Now, next, you use the `torch_get_function` method and retrieve all layers output from the `forward_features` function that is defined in your model. The `torch_get_function` gives a total of 4 outputs as a list and you pick only the first feature and concate across the batches in the end.

```
def torch_get_function(network, loader):
    features = []
    for batch_idx, (inputs, targets) in enumerate(loader):

        print('0', network.forward_features(inputs)[0].shape)
        print('1', network.forward_features(inputs)[1].shape)
        print('2', network.forward_features(inputs)[2].shape)
        print('3', network.forward_features(inputs)[3].shape)
        print()

        features.append([f... for f in network.forward_features(inputs)])
    return [np.concatenate(list(zip(*features))[i]) for i in range(len(features[0]))]

for epoch in epochs:
    dataset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST...
    dataset = torch.utils.data.Subset(dataset, list(range(0, 1000)))
    functloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(...)

    # for x , y in functloader:
    #     print('a ', x.shape, y.shape) 
    # a  torch.Size([100, 1, 28, 28]) torch.Size([100])
        
    activs = torch_get_function(net, functloader)
    print(activs[0].shape)
    break
```

That's why if when I ran your code, I got

```
# These are the 4 output that returned by forward_features(inputs)
0 torch.Size([100, 10, 12, 12])
1 torch.Size([100, 320])
2 torch.Size([100, 50])
3 torch.Size([100, 10])

...

# In the return statement of forward_features -
# You take only the first index feature and concate across batches.
(1000, 10, 12, 12)
```

So, the input size of your model is `(batch_size, 1, 28, 28)` and the final output is like `(1000, 10, 12, 12)`.

---

Let's do the same in [tensorflow](/questions/tagged/tensorflow), step by step.

```
import numpy as np 
from tqdm import tqdm 

import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow import keras 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import (Conv2D, Dropout, MaxPooling2D, 
                                     Dense, Flatten)

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_test = x_test.astype("float32") / 255.0
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (-1, 28, 28, 1))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_test, y_test))
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).batch(100)

# it's like torch.utils.data.Subset
dataset = dataset.take(1000)
dataset
<TakeDataset shapes: ((None, 28, 28, 1), (None,)), types: (tf.float32, tf.uint8)>
```

Let's now build the model. To make it familiar to you, I'm writing in sub-class API.

```
class LeNet(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, num_classes, input_size=28):
        super(LeNet, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = Conv2D(10, (5, 5))
        self.conv2 = Conv2D(20, (5, 5))
        self.conv2_drop = Dropout(rate=0.5)
        self.fc1 = Dense(50)
        self.fc2 = Dense(num_classes)

    def call(self, inputs, training=None):
        x1 = tf.nn.relu(MaxPooling2D(2)(self.conv1(inputs)))
        x2 = tf.nn.relu(MaxPooling2D(2)(self.conv2_drop(self.conv2(x1))))
        x2 = Flatten()(x2)
        x3 = tf.nn.relu(self.fc1(x2))
        x4 = tf.nn.softmax(self.fc2(x3), axis=1)

        # in tf/keras, when we will call model.fit / model.evaluate 
        # to train the model only x4 will return 
        if training:
            x4
        else: # but when model(input)/model.predict(), we can return many :)
            return [x1, x2, x3, x4]

lenet = LeNet(10)
lenet.build(input_shape=(None, 28, 28, 1))
```

Get the desired features

```
features = []

for input, target in tqdm(dataset):
    # lenet(...) will give 4 output as we model
    # but as we're interested on the first index feature... 
    features.append(lenet(input, training=False)[0])

print(len(features))
features = np.concatenate(features, axis=0)
features.shape
(10000, 12, 12, 10)
```

In tensorflow, the channel axis is default set to last, as opposed to the torch. In torch, you received `(1000, 10, 12, 12)` and in tensorflow, it gives you `(10000, 12, 12, 10)` but you can change it of course, ([how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46965196/9215780)). Here is the working [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1-C9j7y3r_k0GmyAaE1M1baUU_BWNtWgo?usp=sharing).